# Best way to install MySQL ODBC Connector on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, odbc

I'm running a FileMaker Server on Ubuntu 22.04 where I've also installed mysql-connector-odbc. Everything has been a test server and now I tried to reinstall everything again. From Scratch. But this time I can't get the mysql-connector-odbc right.

I've tried to install the .deb file but I always get an error.
So I've tried to install the generic .tar file.
But I can't get a connection any longer with my MySQL server.
Any "manuals" to share?